# Request audio access with popup in chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, audio-recording, recordrtc

Considering chrome extensions can't request audio permissions in the manifest.json, I have read that the best way to get permission is to open a pop up asking the user for audio access.

Despite extensive reading I haven't figured out a way to do this? Is there somewhere documenting requesting permission in this way?

Comment: Have you tried checking [chrome.audio](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/audio)?

Comment: @noogui It doesn't seem to have anything that I need. Is this what you were referring to? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/audio

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by opening a new tab after receiving an error callback when capturing the user's media. The function below details this:

```
const captureUserMedia = callback => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    .then(callback)
    .catch(err => {
      window.chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'request-mic.html'
      });
    });
};
```

`request-mic.html` is just an html file with a script tag referencing the `request-mic.js` file that requests microphone permission in the tab. This request is remembered for the extension and you will now have microphone access!

```
<script src="request-mic.js"></script>
```